# asp.net core - AddService using options iniside IServiceCollection extension

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to register my custom service in `Startup.cs`. One of configuration options of this service is ConnectionString. I would like to use this connection string to register dedicated DbContext inside extension, but don't know how to access options (connection string). Is it possible at this level or should I use different approach?

Here's my extension:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddUniLocalizer(
    this IServiceCollection services,
    Action<ServiceOptions> setupAction)
{
    services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IStringLocalizerFactory),
        typeof(UniLocalizerFactory), ServiceLifetime.Singleton));
    services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IStringLocalizer),
        typeof(UniLocalizer), ServiceLifetime.Singleton));

    var connectionString = null; // ????????? How to connection string it from ServiceOptions instance?

    services.AddDbContext<LocalizerDbContext>(
        item => item.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

    return services;
}
```

And usage (Startup.cs):

```
AddUniLocalizer(opt => { opt.conncetionString = "my connection string"; });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With using a Action this is not possible as:

> Action is also a delegate type defined in the System namespace. An
>   Action type delegate is the same as Func delegate except that the
>   Action delegate doesn't return a value. In other words, an Action
>   delegate can be used with a method that has a void return type.

So either you have to use Func or a plain object.

I Suggest to use the last one.

A second thought, why not providing the configuration as you probably want to have the connectionString in your appSettings:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddSecurity(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var appSettings = configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Get<AppSettings>();

        // configure jwt authentication
        var secret = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);
    }
```

Of course you're are using you're own implementation.

Call to this from the startup:

```
services.AddSecurity(Configuration)
```

Configuration it self could be injected int the startup

Comment: Could you provide an example of using a `plain object`?

Comment: Are you sure I can use plain object here? Action<Options> pattern seems to be the part of wider concept of service lifecycle. As far as I understand options can be evaluated "later" than actual service registration.

Comment: Or.. maybe you mean adding another parameter to extension (apart from setupAction)?

Comment: Yes adding another parameter.

Comment: I have added another parameter and it seems to work fine. The idea with reading configuration directly form appsettings is also nice. Thanks for help!